# Can't reach nodejs on port 3000 from external on CentOS 7

Tags: node.js, centos7

I cant reach my node serve on port 3000. When I change port to 80 everything works well.

nodesjs:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log('server listening on port 3000!');
});
```

firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
3000/tcp
```

iptables:

```
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate   NEW                                                                                                                                                             
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate   NEW                                                                                                                                                              
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000 ctstate NEW
```

netstat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1047/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8308/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1730/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1047/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1730/master
```

for me everything looks ok?

Comment: What do you mean? You said you can't access on 3000 but if you change the port to 3000 you can? Doesn't make sense...

Comment: Also, why are you setting 0.0.0.0 as your listening host? Should be set to an actual IP/Hostname or omitted for localhost.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` means listen on each(ipv4) network interface.

Comment: Sorry. Port 80 works I mean.

Comment: Is there any reason why Port 300 should not work? I use firewall-cmd to open port permanent.