# Why can't I talk to a service on tcp/3000 on my CentOS VPS

Tags: dns, routes, port, centos7, firewall

I'm trying to run a second web service on my VPS at port 3000.

On the VPS I run:

```
# php -S myhost.com:3000
```

and then in a browser, navigate to http://myhost.com:3000 but the browser times out and the service logs/outputs nothing.

**If I run the service on port 80** (i.e., php -S myhost.com:80 and navigate to http://myhost.com), it works.

So firewall.  Except that:

```
[root@spinal ~]# firewall-cmd --list-ports
3887/tcp 3000/tcp
```

(the 3887 is another service, which **is** working correctly.)  And I rebooted the VPS after setting up port 3000 in the firewall.  I reckon the service is listening correctly because:

```
[root@spinal ~]# netstat -tupl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:imap            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1907/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ciphire-data    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1876/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1903/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:urd             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2004/master         
tcp        0      0 myhost.com:hbci         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2206/php            
tcp        0      0 localhost.loca:postgres 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1908/postgres       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:smtp            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2004/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:https           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1903/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:imaps           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1907/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 localhost.lo:cslistener 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1878/php-fpm: maste 
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imap               [::]:*                  LISTEN      1907/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ciphire-data       [::]:*                  LISTEN      1876/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 [::]:urd                [::]:*                  LISTEN      2004/master         
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN      2004/master         
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imaps              [::]:*                  LISTEN      1907/dovecot
```

I can however connect locally.  This works, when run on the VPS:

```
$ curl http://myhost.com:3000
```

so that again points at the firewall.  But disabling the firewall doesn't help:

```
# systemctl stop firewalld
```

so it *could* be a DNS problem:  my browser and the VPS differ on what myhost.com resolves-to.  Except that, as mentioned above, switching to port 80 solves the problem.  So it's something to do with coming-in on port 3000, from outside.  But not firewalld.

The question at [Can't reach nodejs on port 3000 from external on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723319/cant-reach-nodejs-on-port-3000-from-external-on-centos-7) is close to mine, but isn't conclusively answered.

Answer (score 2):

I feel pretty stupid.  It **was** a firewall;  not on the VPS, but on my local network.  When I tried it on a machine that doesn't go through my local network, it worked.  I hope my public confession helps someone else.